# ssh xauth error Mac OS 10.6.3

Tags: mac, ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, xauth

Whenever I ssh with X11 forwarding to a remote box from my macbook I get the following error after a few seconds pause:

```
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I took a look at @bryan's answer and the succinct answer he proposed. My interpretation of it is thus. First, the behavior is caused by the use of the -X flag. From the text,

> The warning can be silenced by using ssh -Y, since that is what ssh -X
>   is doing now anyway.

For an explanation of why that may work, read the link. Specifically, the reasoning behind these warnings is

> Trusted X11 forwarding means that you trust the server that you wish
>   to ssh into is not using any keyloggers, screenshot utilities, packet
>   sniffers, or anything else to hijack your connection, in which case
>   X11 will allow it to do whatever a local client would be able to do.

so the -Y is providing this level of trust to avoid warnings. However, that may not be sufficient. I, for example, was trying to silence this message on a Rocks cluster where changes had to be done at the configuration level. You can also silence it via the ssh_config file. According to [this link](https://lists.sdsc.edu/pipermail/npaci-rocks-discussion/2011-September/054878.html) you can add

`ForwardX11Trusted     yes`

into /etc/ssh/ssh_config. However **there are ramifications to doing so.** I am running on a *secure, private network* so the concerns are limited. I will also probably do this on my laptop as well, but I never said I fully understood the concerns myself! If you can express why this may still be risky (I only ssh into computers I know fairly well) then please help clarify in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin-xfree@cygwin.com/msg17927.html

Comment: Welcome at Super User! But, please consider [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) Enjoy!

Comment: If they point you to good information, I think they are.

Comment: I think that at the very least, use a block quote to include an excerpt from said linked page that may answer the question.